# Работа с бинарными файлами C++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
 
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
    int a, n;
    ofstream fileStrmOut( "file.bin", ios::binary );
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
        cout>>"Введите кол-во чисел для ввода:";
        cin >> n;
        cout>> "Введите числа:";
        cin >> a;
        fileStrmOut.write( ( char* ) &a, sizeof(int) );
    }
    fileStrmOut.close();
    ifstream fileStrmIn( "file.bin", ios::binary );
    while ( fileStrmIn.read( ( char * ) &a, sizeof(int) ) ) {
        cout << a << ' ';
     if (a>9 || a<1) cout<<"Числа, которые за границами диапазона:"<<endl;
     cout<<a<<endl;
    }
 
    // закрываем файл
    fileStrmIn.close();
 
    return 0;
}
```

Вот задание:
Написать программу, позволяющую вводить действительные числа, количество которых предварительно задается
пользователем, заносить их в бинарный файл и выполнять их обработку:

- выбрать из файла числа, не лежащие в диапазоне от 1 до 9 включительно, и вывести их на экран в
  отдельных строчках;

– определить и вывести наименьшее число в файле.

Пытался решить задание, но зашел в тупик.
Направьте на правильное решение.

Comment: Судя по сообщению, у вас программа вообще не создалась. Почему именно должен сообщить компилятор. Это точно ВСЕ сообщения?

Answer (score -1):

Если Вы этого ещё не пробовали, то необходимо пересоздать проект в Visual Studio, перекинуть в папку нового проекта **только** файлы с кодом (файлы с расширением .cpp) и хэдеры, если они есть (файлы с расширением .h). В эту же папку закинуть исходные файлы ввода и вывода. После этого необходимо запустить VS, подключить к проекту файлы, которые Вы  перекидывали и собрать-запустить проект